# Car won't start abs just got a starter put on

Tags: starting

[image] I just got a starter put on my truck and now it won't start,  my ABS light is on, it's saying my stability control is off, it won't go in gear or anything, what could be the problem?

Comment: Will the truck turn over? Or do you turn the key and nothing? What year is it? Why did you change the starter in the first place?

Comment: What does this picture have to do with this question?